# Hibernate map <basic, entity> mapping(3 tables)

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, collections, mapping

Let's suppose I've these 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "entity1" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "entity1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "entity2" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "entity1_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "param_name" text NOT NULL,
    "entity3_id" int 4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "entity2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
    CONSTRAINT "fk_entity2_to_1" FOREIGN KEY "entity1_id" REFERENCE entity1("id")
    CONSTRAINT "fk_entity2_to_3" FOREIGN KEY "entity3_id" REFERENCE entity3("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "entity3" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "entity3_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

I need to map entity2 table into my entity1 class, where the type of map's values is Entity3. In other words I need something like this in my "Entity1" Hibernate java bean:

```
public class Holder {

    private Long                 id;

    private String               name;

    private Map<String, Entity3> data;

}
```

Here is where I am currently:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="test">

    <class name="Entity1" table="entity1">
        <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
            <generator class="native">
        </id>
        <property name="activated" column="activated" type="boolean" />

        <map name="data" table="entity2" cascade="all">
            <key column="entity1_id" />
            <map-key column="param_name" type="java.lang.String" />
            < ??????????????????????????? >
        </map>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

< ????????????? > is the part I can't manage to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<???????> -> <many-to-many column="entity3-id" class="entity3" />
```

Hoping this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question answer is many to many mapping see the below link helpful to you

[Many to many mapping in hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/)